# Is it possible to transfer file to endpoint in KAA IoT solution?

Tags: kaa

I am using KAA 0.10 to connect to endpoints and collecting some performance data. Now i want to send some file to the end point, is it possible in KAA?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not transfer any file over KAA, but you can design configuration schema where you can update configuration with Accessible file link and endpoint will get the configuration update notification and your endpoint will download from same link.